# Is it possible to print out a line form Java class that is running

Tags: java

I am running a Java project that takes a Java class bytecode as an input and performs many operations on it. One of the operations that I want to do is that I want to specify a line number that I want to be printed out from the input Java class.

To clarify that, the method should be like:

```
public String getLine(int lineNumber){
   String line = //here should be the code that takes the line number and return the line from the Java class 
   return line;
}
```

Is that possible to do? I have been searching for a long time but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you please add some code to clarify?

Comment: Also state your input/expected output for clarity

Comment: So you want to print a specific source code line from a Java class?  Use some docompiler [e.g procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) and  then loop thought the source file and print it

Comment: I think you need to make your question *much* more detailed. I don't understand exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems doing that:

- Since you want to read bytecode, you can only print out bytecode which is not java source code!
- One java source code command most of the time compiles into multiple bytecode commands.
- If you want to get java code out of it then you would have to parse the bytecode commands and decompile them. BUT you therefore have to know at which command you are atm. I don't see any way to do that.

Can you specify more precise what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically, the project returns some if-statements and I would like to print out these statements from the source code. For example, `I16 Branch 88 IF_ICMPLT L87` is one statement that I want to print out and see what that if-statement is